# Why if statement not compare? List items, resursion

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to add item which has only true value of NodeDir

```
public List<Node> BuildTreeHierarchy(List<Node> node, int? pKey)
{
    if (node.Where(n => n.NodeDir.Equals(true)).Count() > 0)
    {
        return node.Where(n => n.ParentKey == pKey)
        .Select(n => new Node()
       {
           ID = n.ID,
           Name = n.Name,
           Feature = n.Feature,
           NodeDir = n.NodeDir,
           ParentKey = n.ParentKey,
           Left = BuildTreeHierarchy(node, n.ID)
       }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Result:

bear False
monkey True
wolf True
chicken False
stork False  
 
**Now in else part i get null exeption** 
*For example I get all items with false but with true no *

```
public List<Node> BuildTreeHierarchy(List<Node> node, int? pKey)
    {
        var nodesWithNodeDir = node.Where(n => n.NodeDir.Equals(false));
        if (nodesWithNodeDir.Count() > 0)
        {
            return nodesWithNodeDir.Where(n => n.ParentKey == pKey)
            .Select(n => new Node()
           {
               ID = n.ID,
               Name = n.Name,
               Feature = n.Feature,
               NodeDir = n.NodeDir,
               ParentKey = n.ParentKey,
               Left = BuildTreeHierarchy(node, n.ID)
           }).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return nodesWithNodeDir.Where(n => n.ParentKey == pKey)
           .Select(n => new Node()
           {
               ID = n.ID,
               Name = n.Name,
               Feature = n.Feature,
               NodeDir = n.NodeDir,
               ParentKey = n.ParentKey,
             Right = BuildTreeHierarchy(node, n.ID)
           }).ToList();
        }
```

**Here is my logic where i need fill Left and Right Nodes from database**

```
 Storage data = new Storage();
   public  List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>();
   public List<Node> AnimalTree = new List<Node>();
    public List<Node> CreateTree()
    {

        foreach (DataRow animal in data.GetAnimals("select * from AnimalTbl").Rows)
        {
            Node newNode = new Node();
            newNode.ID = Convert.ToInt32(animal["Id"]);
            newNode.Name = animal["Name"].ToString();
            newNode.Feature = animal["Feature"].ToString();
         //   newNode.NodeDir = animal["NodeDir"] == DBNull.Value ? (bool?)null : Convert.ToBoolean(animal["NodeDir"]);
            newNode.NodeDir = Convert.ToBoolean(animal["NodeDir"]);
            newNode.ParentKey = animal["ParentKey"] == DBNull.Value ? (int?)null  : Convert.ToInt32(animal["ParentKey"]);
            nodes.Add(newNode);

        }

        AnimalTree = BuildTreeHierarchy(nodes, 1);
        return AnimalTree;
    }

    public List<Node> BuildTreeHierarchy(List<Node> node, int? pKey)
    {
        List<Node> aa = new List<Node>();
        var nodesWithNodeDir = node.Where(n => n.NodeDir.Equals(true));
        if (nodesWithNodeDir.Count() > 0)
        {
            return nodesWithNodeDir.Where(n => n.ParentKey == pKey)
            .Select(n => new Node()
           {
               ID = n.ID,
               Name = n.Name,
               Feature = n.Feature,
               NodeDir = n.NodeDir,
               ParentKey = n.ParentKey,
               Left = BuildTreeHierarchy(node, n.ID)
           }).ToList();
        } 
         nodesWithNodeDir = node.Where(n => n.NodeDir.Equals(false));
         if (nodesWithNodeDir.Count() > 0)
         {
             return nodesWithNodeDir.Where(n => n.ParentKey == pKey)
                .Select(n => new Node()
            {
        ID = n.ID,
        Name = n.Name,
        Feature = n.Feature,
        NodeDir = n.NodeDir,
        ParentKey = n.ParentKey,
         Right = BuildTreeHierarchy(node, n.ID) 
      }).ToList();
         }
         else
         {
             return new List<Node>();
         }
    }
    }
```

**And here in button click event i need print right Node list where i get null exepction**

```
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cur++;
        PrintTree(nd, cur);
    }
    private void PrintTree(IEnumerable<Node> nodes,int Current)
    {
        foreach (var root in nodes)
        {
          Response.Write(root.Name + " " +root.NodeDir + "<br/>");
          PrintTree(root.Right, Current);     
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tip: Prefer `Any()` over `Count() > 0` as the latter might have to enumerate the sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (DataRow animal in data.GetAnimals("select * from AnimalTbl").Rows)
{
    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.ID = Convert.ToInt32(animal["Id"]);
    newNode.Name = animal["Name"].ToString();
    newNode.Feature = animal["Feature"].ToString();
    //   newNode.NodeDir = animal["NodeDir"] == DBNull.Value ? (bool?)null : Convert.ToBoolean(animal["NodeDir"]);
    newNode.NodeDir = Convert.ToBoolean(animal["NodeDir"]);
    newNode.ParentKey = animal["ParentKey"] == DBNull.Value ? (int?)null  : Convert.ToInt32(animal["ParentKey"]);
    nodes.Add(newNode);
}
//AnimalTree = BuildTreeHierarchy(nodes, 1);
foreach (Node a in nodes)
{
    List<Node> nodeSub = nodes.Where(n => n.ParentKey == a.ID).ToList<Node>();
    a.Left = nodeSub.Where(n => n.NodeDir.Equals(false)).ToList<Node>();
    a.Right = nodeSub.Where(n => n.NodeDir.Equals(true)).ToList<Node>();
}
return AnimalTree;
```

Not using function. Just a single foreach loop to assign Left and Right properties of each item. This is best for performance as well as simplicity.

Notice, when left or right nodes, this code gives you an empty collection, not null.

Comment: hmm but i can only for now fill Left or Right list i need both so i need to make two methods? i can't do anythink in else part, right?

Comment: Fill right? it's null or empty container when count is <= 0. Or I miss your requirement somewhere?

Comment: n.Add(new Node("bear", false));  ->  Left = BuildTreeHierarchy(node, n.ID)
n.Add(new Node("monkey", true)); Right = BuildTreeHierarchy(node, n.ID)

Comment: Its hard to explane, that why i need fillter,because where true i need fill Right list where false i need fill Left list in node class

Comment: hmm can you help me to fill both list Left and Right? :/

Comment: You can just return null or return an empty collection when count is <= 0

Comment: yes its bad because i need somehow fill both list's: right and left, can you say how will make it in your example where you shared?

Comment: OK updated for right. But I didn't work on your Reentrancy issue. Believe there is a performance issue here as well.

Comment: @IrmantasMedeišis can you update above codes on initial values and expected print results, so we can understand your intention with this code?

Comment: Still null acception on right list ;/ ooohh i dont know what do to, i just need that work for not dont care performance

Comment: You have two tasks: 1.) assigning Left or/and Right, and return collection back. Trying to separate these two tasks. Working on this now.

Comment: hmm Okey thx  please update what you mean, you will help me a lot

Comment: @IrmantasMedeišis Updated. I used a single loop to update Left and Right properties for each item in the collection. Make sure my understanding is correct.

Comment: Yes thats perfect!!! thats what i want.. You helped me... BIG thx! But you not even used  BuildTreeHierarchy method?

Comment: Right. I'm not using BuildTreeHierarchy() because of reentrancy issue - That's not good for performance here.

Comment: Yes now everythink works just perfect... I really was stucked on this now even i have better logic without that BuildTreeGierarchy... Now i can go deeper to logic what i want your code just perfect really awsome, BIG THANK YOU ! I'm so happy right now :D

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you're wondering why the list you generate isn't filtered by its `NodeDir` property.  But your code never captures or uses the list that results from the `Where` method in the `if` statement.  Try keeping that list around when you calculate it and use it for further filtering:

```
public List<Node> BuildTreeHierarchy(List<Node> node, int? pKey)
{
    var nodesWithNodeDir = node.Where(n => n.NodeDir.Equals(true));
    if (nodesWithNodeDir.Count() > 0)
    {
        return nodesWithNodeDir.Where(n => n.ParentKey == pKey)
        .Select(n => new Node()
        {
            ID = n.ID,
            Name = n.Name,
            Feature = n.Feature,
            NodeDir = n.NodeDir,
            ParentKey = n.ParentKey,
            Left = BuildTreeHierarchy(node, n.ID)
        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: still same not compare i get all items false and true..:(

Comment: Are you sure you replaced `node.Where` with `nodesWithNodeDir.Where` in the second filter?

Comment: oh yes it's work but now i have other problem with else

Comment: if(nodesWithNoder.Count() > 0) {  Left = BuildTreeHierarchy(node, n.ID) } else { Right = BuildTreeHierarchy(node, n.ID)  } here in else i got null execption

Comment: 1.) In the else part, nodesWithNodeDir doesn't contain any element!
2.) pKey can be NULL!
3.) You are calling BuildTreeHierarchy() inside BuildTreeHierarchy() - Reentrancy issue here.

Comment: I really stucked how to make than else part? :((

Comment: why than only work  var nodesWithNodeDir = node.Where(n => n.NodeDir.Equals(false)); when i make (true)) i dont get anythink?

Comment: @adv12 No return value when (nodesWithNodeDir.Count() <= 0)!

Comment: @Herbert, good catch.  Mostly I was just trying to correct the immediate error he was having; I didn't look for other bugs.